# How to change date field value to year? 8/4/2016 --> 2016

Tags: formula

How can I change data field (date type) to show only YEAR?

When I try to use FORMULA = YEAR(my_custom_date__c) it throws an error.

Answer (score 5):

If the return type of the formula field is Text:

In order to see only the Year of a Date Field you will need to convert it into text. See the following:

```
TEXT(YEAR(My_Custom_Date__c))
```

If the return type of the formula field is Number:

```
YEAR(My_Custom_Date__c)
```

Comment: The Question asker will also have to change the type of their formula field from `Date` to `Text`

Comment: Or use Number and remove `TEXT(...)`.

Comment: I edited my answer. Thank you @AdrianLarson and Derek